# How to make seperate menus that work based on the login

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So for the program I am making, I wanted to make a login that goes to two different menus then go back to the login. I'm not sure how to approach it now.

It goes something like:

```
    string User;
    string Pass;
    int Option;

    void Login(){
        cout << "Enter your username: ";
        cin >> User;
        cout << "Enter your password: ";
        cin >> Pass;
    }

    void Admin(){
        system("CLS");
        cout << "Welcome Admin" << endl;
        cout << "------------" << endl;
        cout << "1. Do something" << endl;
        cout << "2. Do something else" << endl;
        cout << "3. Log out" << endl;
        cout << "4. Quit Program" endl;
        cin >> Option;
    }

    void User(){
        system("CLS");
        cout << "Welcome User" << endl;
        cout << "------------" << endl;
        cout << "1. Do another thing" << endl;
        cout << "2. Do something other things don't do" << endl;
        cout << "3. Log out" << endl;
        cout << "4. Quit Program" endl;
        cin >> Option;
}

        int main(){
        Login();
        if(User == "admin" && Pass == "admin"){
                Admin();
                if(Option == 3){
                // What should I add here if would want to return to login then to user menu
                }
        }
        else
        User();
}
```

Comment: What attribute of the login would decide the menu to use? Do you have a list of admin accounts?

Comment: The admin is hardcoded. I was thinking of using a switch in a switch but i couldn't really figure it out.

Comment: Why a switch within switch? It sounds like a single `if`.

Comment: If you thought of anythign try it, show the code and describe the first obstacle in more detail. Currently the question is too broad.

Comment: I added some more lines of code to show my problem. Please feel free to check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to return to login menu you can use a loop:

```
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        Login();

        if(User == "admin" && Pass == "admin")
        {
            Admin();
        }
        else
        {
            User();
        }

        if(Option == 3) continue;
        if(Option == 4) break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

upd: sorry, forgot about the loop :)

Comment: There's no loop

Comment: @deW1 Now there is a loop.